# Is it possible to get a random value within a group in a group by query?

Tags: sql, oracle, random, group-by, oracle11g

I would like to get *random* values **within a group-by query**, something like this:

```
SELECT city
  , SOME_RANDOMIZER_FUNC(latitude) as "RANDOM_LATITUDE_IN_CITY"
  , SOME_RANDOMIZER_FUNC(longitude) AS "RANDOM_LONGITUDE_IN_CITY"
FROM some_table
GROUP BY city
```

Input:

```
city    LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
STO     -31.3935    -57.9413
STO     -31.0274    -57.8081
STO     -30.7852    -57.7765
STO     -30.4274    -56.4718
NDU     -30.2747    -57.6023
NDU     -32.2909    -58.0737
NDU     -32.0286    -57.8468
NDU     -32.3600    -57.2021
NDU     -32.6816    -57.6541
MBO     -31.7085    -55.9873
MBO     -30.9359    -55.5457
MBO     -31.1972    -55.7574
MBO     -31.7711    -54.6904
```

A desired output:

```
city    RANDOM_LATITUDE_IN_CITY     RANDOM_LONGITUDE_IN_CITY
STO     -31.0274                    -57.9413
NDU     -32.3600                    -57.6541
MBO     -30.9359                    -55.5457
```

Where the function `SOME_RANDOMIZER_FUNC` returns a **random value within the group**.

Comment: There is a group of latitudes and longitudes that belong to the same city. However, one coordinate can belong to one record and the other to another, I don't know if that was the question

Comment: I guess sample data (as well as desired output) would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the input arguments of the random function, you present all the data, then you apply grouping to it, and this is not allowed.
The best way to do this is with the following code:

```
with s_table as (

    select
        city,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        row_number() over(partition by city order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as random_sort
    from
        some_table
    )
    select
    city,
    latitude,
    longitude
from
    s_table
where
    random_sort =1
```

Comment: Same solution as mine, only that I was two minutes late :-) There is no `RAND()` in Oracle. Use `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` instead.

Comment: Yes, every engine has functions to generate a random number. rand(), random() , DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE , etc. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 3):

If you want some non-deterministic row, then you may try [`any_value`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ANY_VALUE.html#GUID-A3C47D5E-B145-40B2-93D2-CA3BA65C2D81) function, documented since 21c:

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select
>   trunc((level - 1)/10) as city
>   , level as lat
>   , 100 - level as lon
> from dual
> connect by level < 101
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
>   city
>   , any_value(lat) as lat
>   , any_value(lon) as lon
> from t
> group by
>   city
> ```
>
> ```
> CITY | LAT | LON
> ---: | --: | --:
>    0 |   1 |  99
>    1 |  11 |  89
>    2 |  21 |  79
>    3 |  31 |  69
>    4 |  41 |  59
>    5 |  51 |  49
>    6 |  61 |  39
>    7 |  71 |  29
>    8 |  81 |  19
>    9 |  91 |   9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=33ebc199622ddc993982361fede7ff6b)*

Comment: The OP emphasized his need for a _random_ value.  That's not `ANY_VALUE()`.  Non-deterministic does not imply random.  I am pretty sure you realized that, but it might improve your answer to clarify that point.

Answer (score 1):

Number your rows randomly per city and then keep those numbered 1.

```
SELECT city, latitude, longitude
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    city, latitude, longitude,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) AS rn
  FROM some_table
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY city;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine FIRST_VALUE with DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE

**For example:**

> ```
> SELECT city, latitude, longitude
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT city
>     , FIRST_VALUE(latitude) OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as latitude
>     , FIRST_VALUE(longitude) OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as longitude
>     FROM some_table
> ) 
> GROUP BY city, latitude, longitude
> ORDER BY city;
> ```
>
> ```
> CITY | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE
> :--- | -------: | --------:
> MBO  | -30.9359 |  -55.5457
> NDU  | -32.6816 |  -57.6541
> STO  | -30.4274 |  -56.4718
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e50235446ecb04e1139f5faa84d02280)*